# If I delete my answer will my comment reply notifications still go through?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

I recently misunderstood a question and gave an answer which did not address what the poster actually wanted. The poster and I exchanged some clarifying comments and he updated his question with more information. I replied to him acknowledging my misunderstanding and very shortly afterwards deleted my answer (so others may be more encouraged to answer).

Assuming he does not check the post for several hours will he still receive the notification of the comment where I acknowledged my error or will it appear that I just deleted my answer after he stated it was not what he was looking for?

Comment: There's a chance that pinged users might spot a message notification, but if they click on that, they'll be lead into void.

Comment: You could just add a comment to the question itself.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Not recommended, because it will stay there forever - at least until somebody flag it or the poster deletes it. The comment is not needed (as Makoto said below)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've had spotty success in this context.  *Sometimes*, I receive the messages on deleted posts.  *Sometimes*, I don't.

This is from the perspective of someone who has 10k+ rep (who can actually see deleted posts), so take this with a grain of salt.  However...I would argue that it's safe to assume that a user will *not* see your messages on a deleted post, especially if they don't have 10k+ reputation to see the deleted *post*.

In that context...would it *really* be worth it to tell someone that your post was wrong without posting a correct answer in its place?  I'm not thinking it is, since comments like that are usually noise anyway and ripe for removal.

**So don't worry about those comments.**  You deleting your answer to make room for more correct answers is commentary enough, in my mind.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for your answer, I was hoping for some absolute expected behavior but I understand functionality can probably vary in a circumstance like this.